# creating a VBScript to grab fonts from fileserver

Tags: vbscript, fonts

I'm trying to create a VBS script that will grab all the fonts from the server font location so that the domain user will have the ability to use them. When I run this script I get a line 15 char 1 error: 800A400C.

Not sure what is wrong with it or if this script will do the job I'm wanting it to do.

```
'On Error Resume Next
'Option Explicit
Dim objShell, objFSO, wshShell
Dim strFontSourcePath, objFolder, objFont, objNameSpace, objFile, strFontsSytem

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesyStemObject")

strFontSourcePath = "\\server\Fonts\"
strFontsSytem = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Fonts") & "\"

Set objNameSpace = objShell.Namespace(strFontSourcePath)
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFontSourcePath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase(Right(objFile, 4)) = ".ttf" Or LCase(Right(objFile, 4)) = ".otf" Then
        Set objFont = objNameSpace.ParseName(objFile.Name)
        If objFSO.FileExists(strFontsSytem & objFile.Name) = False Then
            objFont.InvokeVerb("Install")
            Set objFont = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next

Set objShell = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objNameSpace = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: The share probably requires authentication. Try [mapping the share to a drive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 800A004C means Path not found. Please check the existance of the strFontSourcePath and like Ansgar says also check if the user running this code has access to this share.

Anyway, Here's my code to copy and install fonts from a server share if that is any help

```
Call AddFonts("\\server\Fonts\")
WScript.Quit

Private Sub AddFonts(strFromPath)
    ' install fonts from a server location if not already present
    Dim appShell, objShell, objFSO, colFiles, objFile, objFolder
    Dim strToPath, flags, strFile, strExt

    'SpecialFolder. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176604.aspx
    Const FONTFOLDER = &H14&

    'CopyHere switches
    Const FOF_MULTIDESTFILES        = &H1&
    Const FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE          = &H2&
    Const FOF_SILENT                = &H4&
    Const FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION     = &H8&
    Const FOF_NOCONFIRMATION        = &H10&
    Const FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE     = &H20&
    Const FOF_ALLOWUNDO             = &H40&
    Const FOF_FILESONLY             = &H80&
    Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS        = &H100&
    Const FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR        = &H200&
    Const FOF_NOERRORUI             = &H400&
    Const FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS = &H800&
    Const FOF_NORECURSION           = &H1000&
    Const FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS = &H2000&
    Const FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING       = &H4000&

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = Createobject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set appShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    'create an object for the systems fonts folder
    Set objFolder = appShell.Namespace(FONTFOLDER)

    'make sure these paths end in  a backslash
    strFromPath = FixPath(strFromPath)
    'get the name of the system fonts folder (C:\WINDOWS\Fonts)
    strToPath = FixPath(objShell.SpecialFolders("Fonts"))

    'set flags to install as quiet as possible.
    flags = FOF_SILENT Or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION Or FOF_NOERRORUI Or _
            FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR Or FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS

    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        If objFSO.FolderExists(strFromPath) Then
            Set colFiles = objFSO.GetFolder(strFromPath).Files
            If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
                For Each objFile In colFiles
                    strExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)
                    Select Case LCase(strExt)
                    Case "ttf", "otf"   ' can also be used for "fon", "pfm", "pfb", "afm"
                        'get the complete path and filename for this font file and check if already there
                        strFile = strToPath & objFile.Name
                        If Not (objFSO.FileExists(strFile)) Then
                            objFolder.CopyHere strFromPath & objFile.Name, flags
                        End If
                    End Select
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'cleanup objects
    Set appShell = Nothing
    Set colFiles = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function FixPath(sPath)
    'small helper function to ensure a path ends in a backslash
    If Len(sPath) > 0 And Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FixPath = sPath & "\"
    Else
        FixPath = sPath
    End If
End Function
```